# Can't use my custom skins in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

After the PS3 edition ended, a year afterwards I got Minecraft Java edition on PC on the day the 1.17 update came out. I had custom skins I can use for my Minecraft but when I started the game it just showed up as Steve and it's been doing that ever since the day I got the game, also I can't join any servers or play multiplayer(which is the same thing). I allowed firewall and I still can't play on any servers.

I've tried looking through the internet to see if I could solve this problem but nothing, now my computer is a tad bit outdated and I know it's not my game because I played it on my laptop (skins work and I assume servers too). I don't know if this has been solved. but I would appreciate if someone can answer.

Comment: Welcome to the Arqade! About the skins, have you looked if it's set in the launcher and have you tried setting it from the launcher again? Regarding the server issues, could you try pinging the server? That is, if you can't connect to e.g. hypixel, open `cmd` and type `ping mc.hypixel.net`.

Comment: I have tried many different servers and none work and I have tried to look if it was set in the launcher, but nothing. I'm still not very sure what's going on, but thank you!

Comment: What about the `ping`?

Comment: I have never done a ping?

Comment: If you still can't connect to any server, then try doing one (see my first comment). It's no use trying to fix the game if your computer can't reach the server for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

When you log into Minecraft Java Edition offline, the skins are not uploaded from minecraft.net I think.

Comment: Two things,
1. I don't think the question mentioned anything about being offline? Unless im blind and you can point it out for me.
2. Im pretty sure even if you are offline the launcher saves the skins so that you can use them whilst offline, at least from what I remember I have played minecraft single-player with a skin before (while disconnected from the internet)

Comment: In my experience I have been able to select the skins, but then when I log into the game, it is set to steve. Another explanation could be a corrupt file or something

Comment: Corrupt files could be the case too like you just said.

Comment: Sorry, I suggested the offline because user also could not connect to multiplayer. (For your first point)

Comment: Ah no don't say sorry. I was just a bit confused because I didn't see anything mentioning "offline", your perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the launcher click "SKins" click the skin you want and click "use" If that dosen't work, delete the skin, and put it back on

Comment: I have tried this too, but thank you!

Comment: Wierd, maybe try re-installing the game.

Comment: I hate to say it, but I've tried this several times as well but, thank you!